# Sending many requests in chrome console, but wait in between

Tags: javascript, request, wait, sleep

the UI of my product is not yet fully developed, therefore I often find myself manually sending out fetch requests from the Chrome devtools console. However, sometimes I have to send out requests in bulk, which makes me just loop through them:

```
request.forEach(function(req){
  await fetch(url, req);
});
```

For some reason though, it seems like my server is not OK with this volume, and doesn't properly execute all the requests. I thought that sleeping the thread in between the requests would help, but... how do I actually do that?

setTimeout or setInterval don't seem like good approaches for this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think this is a JS issue and not an issue with your service?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are the only ways to wait a specified amount of time in JavaScript. If you need this, I would suggest using `setInterval`, assigning it to a variable, creating an index variable to keep track of where you are in the array. Increment the index variable by 1 each time. Use an if statement to determine it it's the last item in the array then `clearInterval()` to end the interval.